# How to make PATH inside Region clickable in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Hi I have a use case where I need to draw a complex shape(half-circle here just for demo) which I have done using PATH Uwp class now I need to make inside the region of PATH as clickable(ie user should able to click on the covered area of the shape drawn using PATH). Here is XAML anyone have an idea how to achieve then please share that will help a lot. Thanks

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="300" Background="DarkGray">
                <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Purple" StrokeThickness="4" >
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,100">
                                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                                        <ArcSegment     x:Name="UpperArcSegment"
                                                            IsLargeArc="True"
                                                            Size="20,20"
                                                            SweepDirection="Clockwise"                                            
                                                            Point="200,100" />                                       

                                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry.Figures>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do this using wrapping content in button control anyone has a better approach then, please share. This will make only Path Section clickable.Please make sure to set Path Fill Property to any color or Transparent

```
 <Canvas Width="300" Height="300" Background="DarkGray">
    <Button Click="Button_Click" x:Name="btnUpper">
        <Button.Template >
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
               
                    <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Purple" StrokeThickness="4">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                                    <PathFigure x:Name="UpperArcFigure" StartPoint="0,100">
                                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                                            <ArcSegment     x:Name="UpperArcSegment"
                                                            IsLargeArc="True"
                                                            Size="20,20"
                                                            SweepDirection="Clockwise"                                            
                                                            Point="200,100" />
                                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                                    </PathFigure>
                                </PathGeometry.Figures>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                   
                
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
   
</Canvas>
```